# community server themeing, what changed from 2008 to TS 5.0?

Tags: community-server, telligent

Hoping someone has experience in both community server 2008 and TS 5.0

What are the main differences when in comes to themeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theme/layout system is quite different. Most of what used to exist in a theme (e.g. Fiji) was a set of files that you could customize. Now, those files are in the "generic" theme folder. Instead, you are to create your own "widgets" and add those to your theme.

To create widgets, you'll need to create a new class library and create classes that implement specific Telligent widget classes.

You can read more about the changes on Telligent.com

- [Widgets defined](http://telligent.com/support/telligent_evolution_platform/w/documentation/widgets-defined.aspx)
- [Customization guide](http://telligent.com/support/telligent_evolution_platform/m/mediagallery/1329292.aspx) (free telligent.com login required to download)

Comment: in CS 2008, is it more straight forward, or are they different layers of the application that have to be looked at before editing a theme?

Comment: I personally like CS2008 a lot more. It was move obvious because I could just copy the Fiji theme folder, rename it to my theme, change the instances of "fiji" in the config, and modify the various skins files as necessary. Now in TC5, I need to create a widget library and widgets (ASCX's) then I need to compile and drag those widgets onto the page when in front-end layout edit mode. I'd say they are two different approaches to themeing but they're the same layer but accessed/modified very differently now.

Comment: I believe synchronizing themes is much harder in TC5 since the database stores allot of into also right?

Comment: Theme are essentially the databases's records of what widgets are placed on what pages and where they're located. If you set up a default instance of TC5, login and click Edit Mode in the top ribbon and you will see the ability to drag around and add/remove these widgets. All of that information is really your theme.